# Comparing 2 consecutive Rows of XML using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Hi I am trying to compare the 2 consecutive entries for the following XML.

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Test">
            <wd:Report_Entry>
                <wd:Location_Changes>
                    <wd:EmployeeID>111111</wd:EmployeeID>
                    <wd:CountryCode>US</wd:CountryCode>
                    <wd:RegionCode>RX</wd:RegionCode>
                    <wd:StartDate>2013-07-01</wd:StartDate>
                </wd:Location_Changes>
                <wd:Location_Changes>
                    <wd:EmployeeID>111111</wd:EmployeeID>
                    <wd:CountryCode>US</wd:CountryCode>
                    <wd:RegionCode>MD</wd:RegionCode>
                    <wd:StartDate>2009-09-14</wd:StartDate>
                </wd:Location_Changes>
                <wd:Location_Changes>
                    <wd:EmployeeID>111111</wd:EmployeeID>
                    <wd:CountryCode>US</wd:CountryCode>
                    <wd:RegionCode>MD</wd:RegionCode>
                    <wd:StartDate>2009-10-14</wd:StartDate>
                </wd:Location_Changes>
                <wd:Location_Changes>
                    <wd:EmployeeID>111111</wd:EmployeeID>
                    <wd:CountryCode>US</wd:CountryCode>
                    <wd:RegionCode>RX</wd:RegionCode>
                    <wd:StartDate>2014-07-01</wd:StartDate>
                </wd:Location_Changes>
            </wd:Report_Entry>
        </wd:Report_Data>
```

The output is:

```
    EmployeeID|CountryCode|RegionCode|StartDate    
    "111111"|"US"|"RX"|"2014-07-01"    
    "111111"|"US"|"MD"|"2009-10-14"    
    "111111"|"US"|"MD"|"2009-09-14"    
    "111111"|"US"|"RX"|"2013-07-01""
```

But I am expecting:

```
    EmployeeID|CountryCode|RegionCode|StartDate    
    "111111"|"US"|"RX"|"2014-07-01"    
    "111111"|"US"|"MD"|"2009-10-14"    
    "111111"|"US"|"RX"|"2013-07-01"
```

If there is another consecutive entry with same combination for "EmployeeID|RegionCode", then that entry should not be included.
        I have used the Primary Key to make sure there is no duplicate entry.

I am using the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Test"
                    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
                    version="2.0">
        <xsl:output method="text"
                    omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
        <!-- Variables to hold fillers - pipe, new line, double quotes -->
        <xsl:variable name="delimiter"
                      select="'|'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="linefeed"
                      select="'&#xd;&#xa;'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dQuote">"</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="duplicate_key"
                 match="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Location_Changes"
                 select="concat(wd:EmployeeID,'|',wd:RegionCode)" />
        <!--To remove duplicates-->
        <xsl:key name="primary_key"
                 match="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Location_Changes"
         use="concat(wd:EmployeeID,'|',wd:RegionCode,'|',wd:StartDate)" />
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <!-- Header Row Begin -->
            <xsl:text>EmployeeID</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:text>CountryCode</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:text>RegionCode</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:text>StartDate</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
            <!-- Header Row End -->
            <!-- Data Row Starts -->
            <!-- Parse each and every employee record -->       
            <!--To Reverse the Records and Remove duplicates-->
            <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Location_Changes[generate-id()= generate-id(key('primary_key',concat(wd:EmployeeID,'|',wd:RegionCode,'|',wd:StartDate))[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="position()"
                          data-type="number"
                          order="descending"/>  
                <xsl:call-template name="output">
                    <xsl:with-param name="unique_code"/>                
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="output">
            <xsl:param name="unique_code"/>
            <!-- Data Row Begins -->
            <xsl:if test="$duplicate_key != concat(wd:EmployeeID,'|',wd:RegionCode)">
                <!-- #1 EmployeeID -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$dQuote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:EmployeeID"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$dQuote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <!-- #2 CountryCode -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$dQuote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:CountryCode"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$dQuote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <!-- #3 RegionCode-->
                <xsl:value-of select="$dQuote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:RegionCode"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$dQuote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <!-- #4 StartDate-->
                <xsl:value-of select="$dQuote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:StartDate"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$dQuote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>  
            </xsl:if>       
            <!-- To Remove Consecutive Duplicates-->
            <xsl:variable name="duplicate_key"?
                 match="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Location_Changes"
                 select="concat(wd:EmployeeID,'|',wd:RegionCode)" />    
            <!-- Data Row End -->
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The issue here is I am not able to remove the Consecutive Duplicate

Comment: **1.** How important is the "consecutive" part? Do you want to keep duplicates that aren't adjacent?  **2.** if you define a duplicate as "*same combination for "EmployeeID|RegionCode"*", then why do you include StartDate in the test? **3.** If you're using XSLT 2.0, why don't you use XSLT 2.0 native grouping method?

Comment: 1. Consecutive part is really important. Only consecutive duplicates need to be removed and the adjacent duplicates need to be kept.
2. StartDate is required in the key, as the same EmployeeID|RegionCode can occur after some different entries.
3. The order need to be the same. Can't alter that.

Comment: [shrug] You're saying one thing, and your expected output says another.

Comment: If Row 1 and Row 2 have same EmployeeID and RegionCode, then I should not include Row 2.
If there are multiple Rows with same combination, then I should keep only the first occurance. (provided the combination occurs consecutively)>
If there is some other combination in between, then i should include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there is another consecutive entry with same combination for
>   "EmployeeID|RegionCode", then that entry should not be included.

Unless I'm missing something you should be able to simplify the process by grouping adjacent `wd:Report_Entry` (based on `wd:EmployeeID` and `wd:RegionCode`) and just processing the last entry in the group.

Note: Adjacent means "next to", unlike what you describe in your comment "*Only consecutive duplicates need to be removed and the adjacent duplicates need to be kept.*".

**XML Input**

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Test">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Location_Changes>
            <wd:EmployeeID>111111</wd:EmployeeID>
            <wd:CountryCode>US</wd:CountryCode>
            <wd:RegionCode>RX</wd:RegionCode>
            <wd:StartDate>2013-07-01</wd:StartDate>
        </wd:Location_Changes>
        <wd:Location_Changes>
            <wd:EmployeeID>111111</wd:EmployeeID>
            <wd:CountryCode>US</wd:CountryCode>
            <wd:RegionCode>MD</wd:RegionCode>
            <wd:StartDate>2009-09-14</wd:StartDate>
            <!--remove-->
        </wd:Location_Changes>
        <wd:Location_Changes>
            <wd:EmployeeID>111111</wd:EmployeeID>
            <wd:CountryCode>US</wd:CountryCode>
            <wd:RegionCode>MD</wd:RegionCode>
            <wd:StartDate>2009-10-14</wd:StartDate>
            <!--keep-->
        </wd:Location_Changes>
        <wd:Location_Changes>
            <wd:EmployeeID>111111</wd:EmployeeID>
            <wd:CountryCode>US</wd:CountryCode>
            <wd:RegionCode>RX</wd:RegionCode>
            <wd:StartDate>2014-07-01</wd:StartDate>
        </wd:Location_Changes>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/Test">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:text>EmployeeID|CountryCode|RegionCode|StartDate&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry/Location_Changes" 
      group-adjacent="concat(EmployeeID,'|',RegionCode)">
      <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Location_Changes">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',
      string-join((EmployeeID,CountryCode,RegionCode,StartDate),'&quot;|&quot;'),
      '&quot;&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
EmployeeID|CountryCode|RegionCode|StartDate
"111111"|"US"|"RX"|"2014-07-01"
"111111"|"US"|"MD"|"2009-10-14"
"111111"|"US"|"RX"|"2013-07-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

Some push programming should get you there.  This should adapt easily to 2.0.  Just change the stylesheet and output declarations as needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Test"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('EmployeeID|CountryCode|RegionCode|StartDate','&#xD;&#xA;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="wd:Location_Changes">
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::wd:Location_Changes[1]/wd:EmployeeID = wd:EmployeeID and
                    preceding-sibling::wd:Location_Changes[1]/wd:RegionCode = wd:RegionCode)">

    <xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:EmployeeID,'|',wd:CountryCode,'|',wd:RegionCode,'|',wd:StartDate,'&#xD;&#xA;')"/>

  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank You :)
Works as expected

Comment: I'm glad to hear it.